# ANSI SQL : SPLIT column value INTO ROWS based on aspecific character

Tags: sql

I want to transpose different values within a column separated by a specific character without involving PIVOT function

For the below example different set of courses are separated by semi-colon. The intention is to create different rows whenever it will find a semi-colon. I am not sure how many different set of values will be there under courses separated by semi-colon.

The solution I am looking for using ANSI SQL.

```
Course_Year    Courses
2004           A|B|C|D;E|F|G|H
2005           A1|B1|C1|D1
2006           X1|X2|X3|X4;Y1|Y2|Y3|Y4;Z1|Z2|Z3|Z4
```

Output I am looking for

```
Course_Year    Course
2004           A|B|C|D
2004           E|F|G|H
2005           A1|B1|C1|D1
2006           X1|X2|X3|X4
2006           Y1|Y2|Y3|Y4
2006           Z1|Z2|Z3|Z4
```

Comment: Please mention which database you are using

Comment: The product here is TDV (Tibco Data Visualization) on which the query need to be writen. It doesn't support all functions like Oracle or SQL SQL Server.

Comment: The ANSI SQL way would be a recursive `WITH` (aka cte). But will it run on your dbms?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sql server then you can easily achieve that with **stuff** and **for xml path()**:

```
select distinct t1.Course_Year,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT '; ' + convert(varchar(10), t2.Course, 120)
          FROM courses t2
          where t1.Course_Year = t2.Course_Year
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Courses
from courses t1;
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I want different rows in the output

Comment: Did I just do the opposite? Let me reverse it.

Comment: This is not "ANSI SQL"

Answer (score 0):

To transform ';' separated strings from a column to row you can use strin_split() function with cross apply in sql server as below:

```
select Course_Year,value course from course cross apply string_split(courses,';')
```

**Input:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This is not ANSI SQL